# any View not appearing in the android studio editor

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

when building the app the view i've put in appears but in the editor it is not appearing, and sometimes when i create a ImageView some of the images I pasted in the drawables causes rendering problems. I recently updated my android studio and now it is full of bugs.the image attached below is a new project, I only added image view and convert it to relative layout since constraint layout gives me a ton of errors. thank you for answering my question.[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

P.S.

the image view's src or compatsrc stuff, I've deleted it since it causes errors when building just to test it out. and when opening existing projects the app folder seems to be deleted/moved.

here is the gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rowel.animation"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: try `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: show `gradle` file

Comment: Here is the gradle file @ShubhamVala

Comment: I tried Invalidate Caches/restart still not working. I have searched numerous of fixes online but nothing seem to work. @AbdulKawee

Comment: any chance this is a bug when updating android studio?

Comment: in the picture you can see warning at the end of picture, which has `Refresh` button click that Refresh

Comment: I have the facing same problem, choose a different theme layout editor at top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDK 28 is buggy and has lots of layout issues and program bugs.

---

you can try adding `Base.` to your theme's parent in `styles.xml`

eg:

```
<resource>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
   ...
```

to

```
<resource>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
   ...
```

if doesn't work, then try Invalidating Cache

if that doesn't work either, try changing `targetSdkVersion` to 27 or below

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `27`

and also change this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```